# Checking if empty or using a try/catch?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am spinning up a application in Laravel 5 and I am relatively new to the framework. I am checking if a user's unique key is in the request and the question I'm asking could be across the framework. I am querying the database and using a firstOrFail. I was wondering if there are any advantages to using a try/catch and catching the error or checking if empty?

```
try {
    User::where('identifier', $request->key)->firstOrFail();        
} catch (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e) {
    // Display error
}
```

versus

```
$user = User::where('identifier', $request->key)->first();
if (empty($user)) {
    // Display error
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the try/catch part of your question, I'd avoid the try/catch for a couple reasons. The small reason is that try/catch is fairly slow in PHP. The big reason is that the operation can fail for reasons other than a ModelNotFoundException, and your code will miss that.

Comment: this! if you can't find a user, why is that an exception? you show an error to a user, but there is no error in your program, it's a business logic level error and has nothing to do with exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You should not save passwords as plaintext, you should hash it. Laravel has a class for [hashing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/hashing) that you can use for passwords. When you create a new user do something like this:

```
$user = new User();
...
$user->password = Hash::make($request->get('newPassword'))
$user->save()
```

And to check if credentials are valid

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->get('email');
    $password = $request->get('password');
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->intended('some place');
    }
}
```

For something more detailed check documentation for [Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication)

**Edit**

For the original question, the idea of firstOrFail is that some error will be thrown globally and can be handled by some global [exception handler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#the-exception-handler), if you don't need to throw a global error, then using find() and an *if* statement should be all you need.

Comment: Completely forgot to include the hashed version, just dumbed it down a little bit.

Comment: I should've included a different example such as finding a user.